# Log4net duplicate entries when only one (root) logger is used

Tags: c#, log4net, log4net-configuration, amazon-cloudwatchlogs

My log4net configuration looks like this:

```
<log4net>
 <appender name="CloudWatchLogsAppender" type="CloudWatchAppender.CloudWatchLogsAppender, CloudWatchAppender">
  <layout type="log4net.Layout.PatternLayout">
    <conversionPattern value="%date [%thread] %level %logger.%method - %message%newline" />
  </layout>
  <groupName value="agroupname" />
  <streamName value="astreamname" />
 </appender>
 <root>
  <level value="INFO" />
  <appender-ref ref="CloudWatchLogsAppender" />
 </root>
 <logger name="Amazon">
  <level value="OFF" />
 </logger>
</log4net>
```

In classes, I instantiate the logger with

```
private static readonly ILog Log = LogManager.GetLogger(MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
```

and call the Log.Error(message); only once but in my logs, all the errors are duplicated. Also, this method is being called in a controller class for a WebApi project.

I've read in other questions that it can happen when using multiple loggers and them propagating messages upto the root logger, however, I am only using the root logger in this instance.

Comment: I've also tried removing the Amazon logger there, but it made no difference.

Comment: Are the duplicate log entries exactly the same, down to the millisecond? Or could your application code be logging twice unintentionally?

Comment: They're exactly the same, same time to the millisecond and thread etc.

Comment: I've removed the `visual-studio` and `amazon-cloudwatchlogs` tags, as the question doesn't involve either.

Comment: Try having a look in `log4net.LogManager.GetRepository().GetAppenders()` and see what is returned

Comment: @KevinSmith, this returned 2 identical appenders, even though my XML configuration file only states one.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It seems that the problem was an AWS SDK specific configuration:

```
     <add key="AWSLogging" value="log4net" />
```

Somehow, this duplicated the appenders and caused the double messages.

To fix, just remove this setting or change the value to "none".